# Alpha testing opt-in link is not opening in web browser

Tags: actions-on-google

I was trying to make an alpha release of my app, the opt-in link that has to be shared with the testers is not opening on the desktop browsers but is working fine when directly opened on the mobile device. I am unable to figure out the problem.

Comment: This question is too broad, However I suggest you use the network tab in the  dev console on your browser to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected or at least a known issue. The opt-in link is supposed to be opened on mobile devices and not in desktop browsers.

From [the Google docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments):

> The Actions directory for the web is not supported for opt-in to alpha/beta. Make sure your testers follow the link on their mobile devices (Android or iOS).
>
> When users click on this link, they are directed to the corresponding Action's directory page. They should click on the I'm in button at the bottom of the Action's directory page to opt in as a tester for the first time.